# Import a file from another directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file call `entryPoint.py` :

```
from .commonLib.deviceLib import *
```

And I have a file called `deviceLib.py` :

```
import math
import sys
import logging
import requests
import this

class DeviceLib(object):
    def __init__(self, connectionDb):
        self.__db = connectionDb
```

The tree is like this :

```
/test
    entryPoint.py
/commonLib
    __init__.py
    deviceLib.py
```

When I execute `python entryPoint.py` I get the error : `Attempted relative import in non-package`. Please help me.

Comment: Where are you running entryPoint.py from? Your working directory may highlight the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: General advise: It's better to avoid `import *` if you can, not to get your namespace flooded/overwritten (potentially dangerous). Also do you really need `import this`?

Comment: Noted @colidyre....

Comment: Things to try. 1) Add `__init__.py` to /test. 2) Try running `python test/entryPoint.py` with the first `.` removed from the entryPoint.py import statement.

Answer (score 14):

use *sys.path.append* to append the directory where your python file (module is). E.g if your *entryPoint.py* is inside *address* directory

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/module/address/')
import entryPoint
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be `__init__.py` in the folder both /test and /commonLib reside.

then just do

```
from commonLib import deviceLib
```

For example

```
sound
|-- effects
|   |-- echo.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- reverse.py
|   `-- surround.py
|-- filters
|   |-- equalizer.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- karaoke.py
|   `-- vocoder.py
|-- formats
|   |-- aiffread.py
|   |-- aiffwrite.py
|   |-- auread.py
|   |-- auwrite.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- wavread.py
|   `-- wavwrite.py
`-- __init__.py
```

lets assume you are right now opened wavread.py in format subdirecory, you can import karaoke.py from filters by just

```
from filters import karaoke
```

More information Here,
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_packages.php

Comment: Suppose we have another folder called /sound1 at the same level as /sound and I want to import a file from /sound1.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this will only work if the working directory is `sound/`. If your working directory is `formats/` - this will not work.

Comment: @TD-Asker Thats true. you should be in the main directory where everything else is residing. The reason you can packages then sound and host it into pypi to be installed  by pip. once installed by pip, you can be any directory in your computer but be able to import sound and sub scripts in sound

Comment: @MenfisMenfis then sound and sound1 should be in a common directory having `__init__.py`. the common directory is the main directory and is your package name.

Comment: if I run the script from commandline, without tweaking sys.path, it still complains about `no module of name ...`

Answer (score 0):

To import a file from another directory you can use this code :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'folder destination')
import file
```

As you can see here we included the path so python will look for the file in that path as well.

Comment: sys.path.insert is going to add that path so python will look in that directory for your file as well.

Comment: Yes, or you could use the `import` system? It's not the easiest, for sure, but you shouldn't need to mess with `sys.path`

Comment: Although this is one solution, consider the idea that you may want to conduct multiple relative imports from multiple sub-directories etc. - it's impractical to insert each directory to each script one-by-one...

Comment: About that you can read this : https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the answer you provided.