# Easiest way to import a function from a file in a different folder

Tags: python

Can I import a python module from a distant folder? (Possible duplicate of [How to import a Python module from a sibling folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/how-to-import-a-python-module-from-a-sibling-folder))

Comment: could you provide a link to the git hub repo which you cloned?

Comment: https://github.com/roemera/breakfast-club-python and I'm trying to get to barnard.py within the barnard folder and create an object of the 'Barnard' class.

Comment: There are many ways to install dependencies. You want a package manager.  `git` is not a package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the git repo should have a requirements.txt if it is for general use. If it has one then you can run `pip install requirements.txt`

It is also fairly easy for the repo owner to generate this file. At the root of their project they can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. `pip freeze` lists all current dependencies and so this command outputs the result to `requirements.txt`.

As for your second point, it really depends on the package structure. If they want to expose the code in the package they may have imported it in one of the top level `__init__.py` files. Otherwise, you can always directly import by following the paths.

For example if your structure is:

```
project
    folder
        subfolder
            module
```

And module has a function called foo then you can import `foo` like so: `from project.folder.subfolder.module import foo`. Of course this assumes each of these directories has its own `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest places to look for packages using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/module/address/')
```

Source: [Import a file from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149113/import-a-file-from-another-directory)